# Как правильно сложить?

Tags: jquery

Как правильно сложить?

```
var getvalue2 = $('td.product-price');
var getvalue3 = $("input[class='input-text qty text']");
var getvalue4 = $('td.product-subtotal');
for (var i=0; i<getvalue2.length; i++) {
var result1 = getvalue2.eq(i).text() + getvalue3.eq(i).val() + getvalue4.eq(i).text() + ";";
var result2 = result2 + result1;
}
console.log(result2);
```

Консоль выдает:

```
                        р.35                        
                                                8
                        р.280                       ;
```

А должно быть       р.35  8 р.280;

Прощу сильно не пинать)) Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, то вам нужно задействовать метод [$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

Comment: а чем это лучше нативного метода строки trim ?

    getvalue2.eq(i).text().trim() + getvalue3.eq(i).val().trim() + getvalue4.eq(i).text().trim()

Comment: в большинстве случаев ничем. Отличия начинаются например в IE8, где нативный метод строки .trim() не работает.

Comment: так полифилл простой, использовать полифиллы, если они соответствуют стандарту вполне можно, и даже нужно.